# HTTP request always returns 408 error in PuTTY

Tags: http, httprequest, telnet, putty

I am a beginner in HTTP and web sockets.
I'm trying to test an HTTP connection via Telnet with PuTTY.
I do a connection to `www.geekthis.net` (for example) at port 80.
It connect and when I write `GET /index.php HTTP/1.0` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

It returns a 408 error "request time out".

Comment: You probably type the request too long. Prepare ii in a clipboard before connecting and paste it by right-clicking the PuTTY window.

Comment: I did it this way but it returns the error above

Comment: Did you sent an empty line after the `GET`? (basically you need two "enters" after the `GET`)

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you sent an empty line after the GET?

Basically you need two "enters" after the GET.